# Why can't I type into a read-only file in VSC for Mac?

Tags: c++, macos

I am a beginner that has been using Visual Studio Code for about a week. I came across a problem that I can not figure out after running my code. Every time I try to type/input something into the terminal, it gives me a "can not edit read only " message. Is there a way to switch this off?

[image: Read Only Input Message]

Comment: How do I run sudo?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, its just that the editor in the output section is not letting me Enter Last Name because it is saying that it is read-only

Comment: Perhaps you should read about [file system permissions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm)? You may need to change permissions using (eg) `chmod` or `chown`

Answer (score 0):

This plugin comes real handy just for this case... Find the instructions about how to toggle off the readonly falg in the plugin description https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShemeerNS.Read-OnlySwitch ....... What might be the reason for this can one among below

Have you added the project to source control?

Have you marked the project folder (and all it's sub folders) as read only?

Of course, someone else may have done either of these things if they have had access to your machine.

Comment: I tried installing the switch but I cant open the files.

Comment: Did u try opening the same file in notepadd++ and after opening right click on the tab bar and try selecting clear radonly flag ?? Or after opeing goto edit and click clear read only flag and try eding and saving ?